# Naive question about polynomial time reducibility

Tags: computational-complexity

> **Question**:
>   is it known, whether there is an upper bound on the exponent of the fastest polynomial-time reduction from $\mathrm{3SAT}$ to $\mathrm{NP}$-$\mathrm{hard}$ problems or, can it be proved that for every problem requiring an $\Theta(n^k)$ time reduction, there is a problem requiring an  $\Omega(n^{k+1})$ reduction from $\mathrm{3SAT}$?

Additional, secondary question:
Which $\mathrm{NP}$-$\mathrm{hard}$ problem requires the polynomial time reduction from $\mathrm{3SAT}$ with the highest exponent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unlikely there is any upper bound.  To see the problem, consider the (artificial) problem

$\text{3SATpad} = \{ \phi \#^{|\phi|^{100}} : \phi \in \text{3SAT}\}$,

where $\#$ is some new symbol.  $\text{3SATpad}$ is in $\mathsf{NP}$, and there is an obvious $O(n^{100})$-time reduction from $\text{3SAT}$ to $\text{3SATpad}$.  But it's doubtful there's even an $O(n^{99})$-time reduction.  Otherwise, one could solve $\text{3SAT}$ in $2^{O(n^{.99})}$ time (unlikely, as this violates the Exponential Time Hypothesis), as follows:

1. On input $\phi$ of length $n$, run the reduction producing string $y$.  The key point here is that $|y| \leq O(n^{99})$.
2. If $y$ is not of the form $\psi \#^{|\psi|^{100}}$, reject.
3. Otherwise, since $|\psi \#^{|\psi|^{100}}| \leq O(n^{99})$, it must be that $|\psi| \leq O(n^{.99})$.  Now decide if $\psi \in \text{3SAT}$ in $2^{O(n^{.99})}$ time, using a naive brute-force algorithm.  This gives the correct answer about satisfiability of $\phi$.

Perhaps one can even prove the impossibility conditioned only on $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ (rather than on E.T.H.), by a Ladner's Theorem-type argument...

Comment: Can’t you prove it *unconditionally* using the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem?

Comment: Seems possible, yes.

Comment: On second thoughts, it may not be so easy. The assumption that 3SAT reduces to any NP-complete language in $O(n^k)$ time implies (and is, in fact, equivalent to) that for every $L\in\mathrm{NP}$ and every constant $c$, $L$ can be decided by a deterministic polynomial-time computation (with exponent only depending on $L$) followed by an $O(n^{1/c})$-time nondeterministic computation. However, I couldn’t get this to contradict the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem.